# Why won't my Three.js object move when I tell it to?

Tags: javascript, three.js, position

I am trying to create a three.js block that will move when I press different keys. I have been successful with creating a functional `eventListener`, checking using `console.log()`, and also been successful with moving my block, but when I put both together, the block doesn't move. I've also tried using the successful block moving code and looping it so I can see that it moves on command, and the block has `__dirtyPosition` set to true, but even that didn't move it.

I'm a fairly experienced programmer, and have created many working programs like this one, but for some reason it just isn't working, even though I've compared it to my working programs and nothing's different.

```
var block1 = new Physijs.ConvexMesh(
  new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x444444})
);
block1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
block1.__dirtyPosition = true;
scene.add(block1);
```

the `eventListener`:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var code = event.keyCode;
  //a, s, w, d respectively
  if (code === 65) block1.translateX(-3);
  if (code === 83) block1.translateY(-3);
  if (code === 87) block1.translateY(3);
  if (code === 68) block1.translateX(3);
});
```

and the `renderer`:

Top of the code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Bottom of the code:

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Show the code for it

Comment: Make sure block1 object is accessible in your EventListener function.

Comment: Do you have a render loop? Are you asking the scene to render() ?

Comment: waiting to see if there was a render loop here :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I needed to loop the `renderer`, I thought it did it on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Radio, I realized I had completely forgotten to loop the renderer.
I just changed this

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

to

```
function animate() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  setTimeout(animate, 20);
}
animate();
```